# Spring 4.1.5 MVC ErrorHandler always catches ClassCastException when using MyBatis

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, mybatis

I'm using Spring 4.1.5 and MyBatis 3.2.8.  Below is a simple representation of the code I have.  A controller has a reference to a service, which has a reference to a DAO, which uses MyBatis to query the database.

All of this works great except whenever there is an exception, the front-end always gets a variant of `java.lang.ClassCastException:org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException
cannot be cast to java.util.List`.

**MyController.java**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/list}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<List<String>> getCodes() {
    List<String> response = myService.getCodes();
    return new ResponseEntity(response, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

**MyService.java**

```
public List<String> getCodes() {
    return myDao.getCodes();
}
```

**MyDao.java** (extends `SqlSessionDaoSupport`)

```
public List<String> getCodes() {
    return getSqlSession().selectList("Codes.selectCodes");
}
```

So an `UncategorizedSQLException` is getting thrown because of a malformed query (sometimes it's a `BadSQLGrammarException`, etc).  Jackson attempts to serialize the exception to the expected `ResponseBody` of `List<String>`.  This can't be done, so a `ClassCastException` gets thrown instead.

I want to capture the underlying exception and return that to the front-end.  I thought that implementing an exception handler in the controller would do the trick, so I modified **MyController.java** to include the following exception handler.

```
@ExceptionHandler(UncategorizedSQLException.class)
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<String> handleUncategorizedSQLException(UncategorizedSQLException se, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

    return new ResponseEntity<String>(se.getMessage(),HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
}
```

Unfortunately, this never gets called.  If I setup an exception handler for `ClassCastException`, then I do get into the exception handler, but what I want is to catch the exception before Jackson ever starts trying to serialize the response body.

I'm sure this is possible, and I'm just missing some configuration step.  Any idea what I'm missing?  Your help is greatly appreciated!! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm ashamed for not testing my own example.  Everything works fine.  The problem in my *real* code was that someone wired up an AOP method to log the service calls.  The AOP method was swallowing the exception thrown by the database and simply returning it.

So it had nothing to do with the serialization.  The ClassCastException was getting thrown within the controller, because the exception was being assigned to the return object, which clearly didn't work.

I'm sorry for wasting everyone's time.